# @angular/core is not getting update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I update My Angular Project from Version 7 to 12 "version by version".

here is the `ng --version` of the project

```
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 7.20.5
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.9
... animations, cdk, cli, common, core, language-service
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core            9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.9
@angular/compiler               9.1.13
@angular/compiler-cli           8.2.14
@angular/forms                  10.2.5
@ngtools/webpack                8.3.29
@schematics/angular             12.2.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      3.5.3
```

where it is showing me  `@angular/cli` and `@angular/core` is on version `12.2.9`

but when I am running `ng update` then it is saying

```
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cli                       12.2.9 -> 12.2.10        ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                      8.2.14 -> 12.2.10        ng update @angular/core
```

When I am running this `ng update @angular/core@12.2.9`
then I am getting this message

```
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
✔ Package successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 82 dependencies.
Package '@angular/core' is already at '12.2.9'.
```

Comment: try updating one major version at a time. This is what the ng docs suggest. https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-12.0

Comment: Hi @joshvito I update it version by version first I update it from 7 to 8 then 8 to 9 and up to 12

Comment: yes, if your goal is to get from 7 to 12, you should update 7=>8, 8=>9, 9=>10, 10=>11, 11=>12;

Comment: @joshvito do I need to update these packages to version 12 as well
@angular/compiler               9.1.13
@angular/compiler-cli          8.2.14 
The project is working fine on these versions when I am updating them to any later version then the project is giving pages of errors.